# Parse String to Date

Tags: java, string, parsing, date, typeconverter

```
String str_date = currentMonth + 1 + "-" + value.toString() + "-" + currentYear;
            DateFormat formatter ; 
            Date date = null ; 
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
            try {
                date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);
            } 
            catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
            System.out.println(date);
```

Hi, I tried to search for string to date and almost everyone uses this kind of code but it seems to still print out null? Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at what's actually in `str_date` before parsing?

Comment: Please don't do this.  It's wrong in so many ways.

Comment: ...and once you've done that, maybe use the formatter to format an actual date (`new Date()`) to make sure that what you see is consistent with what you are expecting

Comment: It prints out ex. 12-01-2012.

Comment: Please spend some time in understanding the Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try either

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

or

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

depending on what you actually want. Your code suggests you might want to have a month as the first part of your pattern.

Make sure that `currentMonth + 1` is what you want. If the `currentMonth` is 12, then `+1` will push the date to January the next year.

Also, try to get used to use a `Locale`, too. the default one might work for you, but will break on someone else's computer.